# ASA5505 powering off and UPS questions

Tags: cisco-asa

I'm new to the ASA 5505 and I have a few power related questions.

The unit is powered on when the power adapter is connected, but what is the "proper" procedure for powering OFF the device? Do I just unplug the power cable from the device?

I'm planning on connecting the ASA to a UPS that's being used for other stuff. My question is related to power failure. Do I need to send a command to power off the ASA before power is removed? Also, will the ASA power back on once the UPS senses that the building power is restored?

I want to make sure I don't damage the device ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn the device off, unplug the power cable. When utility power is restored, the unit will come back up. There's no power switch.

Comment: Just don't plug it back in too quickly, or repeatedly plug/unplug it. No electronics like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've worked directly with the ASA specifically, but as long as the running config has been saved (which likely it has), no specific shutdown procedure is required.